# How to work with tabhost,tabwidget and framelayout?

Tags: android-tabhost, tabwidget

I am using this code

```
package com.example.tabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();

        TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Sími");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.Sími);
        spec1.setIndicator("Sími");

        TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Sms");
        spec2.setIndicator("Sms");
        spec2.setContent(R.id.Sms);

        TabSpec spec3=tabHost.newTabSpec("Net");
        spec3.setIndicator("Net");
        spec3.setContent(R.id.Net);

        TabSpec spec4=tabHost.newTabSpec("Greina");
        spec4.setIndicator("Greina");
        spec4.setContent(R.id.Greina);

        tabHost.addTab(spec1);
        tabHost.addTab(spec2);
        tabHost.addTab(spec3);
        tabHost.addTab(spec4);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

with this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TabWidget
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    />

     <FrameLayout
         android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" >


     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/Sími"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="340dp"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:paddingTop="60px" >

     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Sms"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="60px"
     >


     </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Net"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="60px"
     >

     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Greina"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="60px"
     >


     </LinearLayout>
     </FrameLayout>

    </TabHost>
```

I am new to android eclipse. I made 4 tabs(linearlayout) inside this tabview. But it is difficult to set the location on a button in one tab. How can i work with this 4 types of tabs like i am working with 4 xml files, is that possible ? How can i make the tabwidget smaller without the text not going away? , i hope this makes sense.